# Running Python on USB

Tags: python, mobile, usb

I'm trying to set up a USB I have with a full Python suite. I want to be able to download modules and other useful libraries to the thumb drive, create scripts and modules of my own and even export programs, all from the USB. I want to do this so that I can work on projects from any computer without having to download any software to that particular PC.

I think I have to create a virtual environment on the USb first, but beyond that I'm not sure if its possible or feasible to accomplish this.

Any advice on how to proceed, if I can?

Comment: I suppose a [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) is what you exactly need. besides, you can use [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true) for using python on the go.

Comment: You can create a venv like @MahradHanaforoosh advised, but if you wish to use an IDE and other stuff on the go, I recommend using a docker.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already installed python on windows and added it in your `PATH`. for making a python virtual environment do these steps:

### Step 1: Change Directory

open `cmd` and write your `UBS` assigned letter + `:` to change the directory. assuming your `USB` is mounted as `D` volume.

```
C:\Users\Name>D:

D:\>
```

### Step 2: Creating Virtual Environment

```
D:\>python -m venv otg
```

you can substitute `otg` with any name you want.

### Step 3: Activating Virtual Environment

```
D:\>otg\Scripts\activate.bat
```

now you are in the created virtual environment. the `CMD` prompt must be sth like this

```
(otg) D:\>
```

install whatever you want. to confirm that everything is Ok, the `where python` command in cmd must return sth like this:

```
D:\otg\Scripts\python.exe
```

### Step 4: Exiting From Environment

after you finished your work you can exit the virtual environment by issuing this command

```
(otg) D:\>deactivate
```

Now you can unplug your `USB` and attach it to any other system. to access the python environment you just need to repeat steps `1`, `3` and `4`. for more information about virtual environments [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) is a good source.